# Python dataframe rows contains multiple list of string search

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of elements in string format that I want to search in each row and delete others.

The code below works fine.

However, it replaces the search from the last element of the list.

I am trying to capture every results from the list 'l'.

Please see below for input and expected output.

Code:

```
l = ['Testing','Goals are met','Mathematics subject','tesTed prototype','Some Test']
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
df.columns = ['l']
```

Input Data:

```
    l
0   Testing
1   Goals are met
2   Mathematics subject
3   tesTed prototype
4   Some Test
```

Code to capture the strings contains:

```
select_list = ["Math",'Test']

for s in select_list:
    # keeping into a dataframe
    df1 = df[df.l.str.contains(s,case=False)]

df1
```

Expected output: Notice the code above didn't select the string 'Math' from above.

```
l
0   Testing
2   Mathematics subject
3   tesTed prototype
4   Some Test
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that you are reassigning to `df1` with every iteration of the `for` loop.

Instead of doing so, you should use a *regular expression*:

```
filtered_df = df[df['l'].str.contains('|'.join(select_list), case=False)]
```

Output:

```
                     l
0              Testing
2  Mathematics subject
3     tesTed prototype
4            Some Test
```

The above `.join` call produces the string `'Math|Test'`, which, when passed to `.str.contains`, tells it to look for all rows which contain at least one of `'Math'` and `'Test'`. If you add more strings to `select_list`, then it will look for them too.

Note that in certain cases (say, if strings in `select_list` contain special characters like "."), this approach may require modification.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
select_list = ["Math",'Test']
df1 =  pd.DataFrame([], columns = ['l'])
for s in select_list:
    df1 = pd.merge(df1, df[df.l.str.contains(s,case=False)], how='outer')
```

alternate: instead of using `dataframe` in the `loop` you can also use `list` to capture the result and create the `dataframe`

```
l2 = []
for s in select_list:
    l2.extend(df[df.l.str.contains(s,case=False)].values.tolist())

df3 = pd.DataFrame(l2)
df3.columns = ['l']
```